# module.js:339 throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog' on WINDOWS 8 Pro

Tags: npm, npm-install

`[module.js:339 throw err;`

> Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog' on WINDOWS 8 Pro

I have tried to reinstall nodejs but still not working on windows.

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:18:11
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:75:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this problem on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

[This is caused by backwards incompatibilities with Node versions.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2814)

You can fix this by deleting all old (incompatible) Node modules:

- *nix

  - `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node_modules`
- Windows

  - `rmdir %appdata%\npm\node_modules /s /q`

Comment: For CentOS 7 (i think 6 too): /usr/lib/node_modules

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and I just deleted all the contents in `%appdata%\npm-cache`. Don't know yet if it helped or not ...